# Show that $f(x,y)=\left(x^4+y^4\right) \log \left(x^2+y^2\right)$ with $f(0,0)=0$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Show that $f(x,y)=\left(x^4+y^4\right) \log \left(x^2+y^2\right)$ with
>   $f(0,0)=0$ is continuous.

Can't seem to show that the partial $\frac{2 x \left(x^4+y^4\right)}{x^2+y^2}+4 x^3 \log \left(x^2+y^2\right)$ is bounded.

Comment: I would do a substitution $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ in the original $f(x,y)$ and use some $r<\epsilon$

Comment: My suggestion: write it as $\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\cdot(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: You cannot use practical rule since the gradient is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. You have to do the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t\log\, t \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ and $|f(x,y)| \leq |t\log\, t|$ for $x^{2}+y^{2} <1$ where $t =x^{2}+y^{2}$.

Comment: Sorry how does this help...?

Comment: If $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|t \log\, t|<\epsilon$ for $|t| <\delta$. Hence $|f(x,y)| <\epsilon$ for $x^{2}+y^{2}<\delta$ which tells you that $f(x,y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Oh ok.  And we know the function is continuous elsewhere because it is a combination of continuous functions?  We just needed to test $(0,0)$?

Comment: @helios321 Right. There is no problem with continuity at other points.